# Invoking EJB method from JUnit - "No such EJB method"

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I'm trying to call a method on a remote EJB in a JUnit test that will run SQL against a DB and return results.  Here's the message from the exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such EJB method org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBMethodLocator@3c2f505 found on SiViewDBFacadeEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/SiViewDBFacadeEJB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/SiViewMMDBAccessBean

First of all, this error seems to be intermittent.  I have a couple different methods in the EJB that run different SQL and return results as a HashMap.  In my JUnit test I was calling these methods back to back and I was noticing that the call to the second method was always failing even if I switched the order of the calls.  Just recently I tried calling the exact same method twice and it comes back the first time but fails the second time.

Does this problem signature ring a bell with anyone.  I'm somewhat new to working with EJBs but this problem seems strange in its inconsistent nature.

Thanks all.

Comment: What container are you running in? Are you using something like Arquillian?

Answer (score 1):

most common reason for this this error to occur is the EJB is not initialized  or not deployed at all to the server that hosts it. Look at the logs on both client and server side to make sure all necessary components are initialized and running.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Not sure my case qualifies here because as I stated in my initial blurb, it would seem the invocation of the method ALWAYS works the first time and then fails on subsequent invocations.  If it was not deployed at all I don't know how I could get a response back the first time.